# Import custom library in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have `web app` and `Ember app` in iframe. I want to import custom library from `web app` to `ember app` like global variable. Library look like object with function:

```
var helpers = {
    helper1: function() {},
    helper2: function() {}
};
```

Library working with sockets and will the same for both applications.

I wrote:

```
app.import("./../../../public/scripts/js-helpers.js"); //file located in web app
```

I can't access variable `helpers` in project and ember-cli copy folder `public` into their working folder. Sorry if question is stupid, I can't understand `ember-cli` import principles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll propose one solution, which I find to be the easiest. You won't have globally scoped variables, but you use then ES6 module approach.

For example purposes, let's say you have a file under `app_name/lib/` called `helper.js`. `lib` is a directory you create for holding your custom libraries. You don't have to use that name. Use the `export default` command as such:

```
export default {
    helper1: function() {},
    helper2: function() {}
};
```

Then, lets say you need this in a route. Here could be one such route:

```
import helper from 'app_name/lib/helper';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(){
      helper.helper1();
}
```

`helper` is the name of what you imported, and represents the object that you exported in your `helper.js`. This method seems to be the style in which Ember-CLI suggests you should use

Comment: Thanks, it works. But how I can import files outside the ember root directory. Ember search only tmp directory`ember/chat/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-5dhDCkaV.tmp/../../../public/scripts/js-helpers.js`  and after build (with '/../../../') make wrong path.