# Using LoDash with EmberCLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, lodash

Does anyone have a working example of a (simple) ember-app project built using Ember-CLI that uses LoDash? (e.g.: I want to use lodash, _.someLodashFunc, in my Routes and Controllers).

I haven't seen any thread / article on the web that gives clear, step-by-step explanation on how to do that.

If possible with lodash v3.0.0 (and I'm using the latest ember-cli, v0.1.9).

Thanks,
Raka

---

I found out how, you need to generate a custom build of lodash (the "lodash modern"). Use lodash-cli: https://lodash.com/custom-builds

On the command console type: lodash modern ..., and you'll get a javascript file generated: lodash.custom.js

Put that file under "vendor" dir of your ember-cli project.

Modify the Brocfile, add this:

```
app.import('vendor/lodash.custom.js', {
  'lodash': [
    'default'
  ]
});
```

And that's it.... you don't have to do "import _ from 'lodash'" in any of your js files. In fact, don't do that (you'll get an error). The _ var is readily available.

For example, I have a Route object like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    console.log('hohoho: ' + _.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
    return Ember.Object.create({name: 'Raka'});
  }
});
```

And I could see hohoho:,b,c,d got printed in javascript console when I visited that route.

### CORRECTION

You don't really need that lodash-cli.

I've tried this way (I guess more proper):

1. bower install lodash --save
2. In Brocfile.js, have this line: app.import('bower_components/lodash/lodash.js');

That's it. _ is automatically available in your Routers / Controllers.

I did the same with d3:

1. bower install d3 --save
2. In Brocfile.js, have this line: app.import('bower_components/d3/d3.js');

And variable named 'd3' is automatically available.

---

Added related link:

1. [Import custom library in ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554236/import-custom-library-in-ember-cli)
2. http://tiku.io/questions/2866484/how-to-include-a-local-javascript-im-ember-cli-application (quote: If you don't need them to minified in your vendor.js file you can put them in the public/js and then include it as a normal script file in app/index.html. I use this method for some libraries like moment.js. The public folder gets directly copied to your site root during the build.)
3. [Proper way to access third party libs such as D3 in Ember CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27278368/proper-way-to-access-third-party-libs-such-as-d3-in-ember-cli)

Comment: As a side note, be aware that much of LoDash functionality is redundant to what is provided by `Ember.Enumerable`.

Comment: Thanks for the info (didn't know it existed). But I need to import lodash anyway, since I'm incoporating a component that uses D3js and uses lodash. Now I'm trying to find out how to include D3js in ember-cli project.

Comment: *Brocfile.js* is now called *ember-cli-build.js*

Comment: > you can put them in the public/js and then include it as a normal script file in app/index.html

I would recommend against this to avoid the extra connection/request. You also don't know when this will be loaded with regard to your ember app booting.

Answer (score 9):

You can use something ready: 
https://github.com/levanto-financial/ember-lodash
or do it manually.

I don't have any example but it should be as easy as modifying these 3 files:

#### bower.json

Just add the line

```
"lodash": "4.16.4",
```

to your `dependencies` and run `bower install` in your command line.

Alternatively, you can install it via `bower`:

```
$ bower install lodash --save
```

#### Brocfile.js

In order to be included to sources by Broccoli:

```
app.import('bower_components/lodash/lodash.js');
```

add this somewhere after `var app = new EmberApp();`

#### .jshint.rc

Add the line:

```
"_": true,
```

somewhere in the `predef` section (if you don't want to see the warnings like `_ is undefined`).

I haven't tested that but I hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this one, and getting these errors in "ember serve" console:

app.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: '_'.

1 error

router.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: '_'.

1 error

===== 2 JSHint Errors

Path or pattern "bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js" did not match any files

Comment: hey, do you remember what the problem was about? was it just an unnecessary `dist` folder in the path?

Answer (score 5):

You can install the latest stable version using Bower. In your project's root directory, run:

```
bower install lodash --save
```

Then import it using Brocolli by adding this line in your `Brocfile.json` somewhere after `var app = new EmberApp( ...`:

```
app.import('bower_components/lodash/lodash.js');
```

Answer (score 4):

ember-lodash addon would be best pet.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-lodash)

install addon :  `ember install ember-lodash`

To include string functions alone

```
import _string from 'lodash/string';

let truncatedString = _string.trunc(rawString);
```

To include entire lodash library,

```
import _ from 'lodash/lodash';

let truncatedString = _.trunc(rawString);
```