# ember - How to correctly add bootstrap rows/cols based on number of records in model?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a route `groups.index` that showcases all the groups in my app. In the route I use the `this.store.findAll('group');` to fetch all the groups and in the groups.index template I use the each to go through each group. I want to make it so that each group is contained within a bootstrap `col-md-3` class, so that I can make 4 "panels" for each row showcasing the groups.

I made a helper class for handlebars that determines whether the index is at 0, or a multiple of 5, to determine where to start a row. I then use the same function to determine whether the index is a multiple of 4 to determine where to add the closing tag for a row. However I get a build error since I am not closing the divs within each `{{#if}}` block. Is there a way to make this work? Or is there a simpler way that I am missing?

`groups.index` template

```
{{#each model as |group index|}}

{{#if (isMultiple index 5)}}
<div class='row'>
{{/if}}

<div class='col-md-3'>
{{#link-to 'groups.show' group.id}}{{group.name}}{{/link-to}}
</div>

{{#if (isMultiple index 4)}} 
</div>
{{/if}}


{{/each}}
```

helper function

```
export function isMultiple(params) {
  if (params[0] == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  const index = params[0] + 1;
  const multiple = params[1];
  return (index % multiple == 0);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(isMultiple);
```

Comment: convert  your model to the required format using the computed property and iterate it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by converting it to the required format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create computed property depends on the `model` property. and chunk model by 4 and iterate it in hbs.

For preparing the model,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import _array from 'lodash/array';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    chunkSpan: 4,
    resultModel: Ember.computed('model', function() {
        return _array.chunk(this.get('model').toArray(), this.get('chunkSpan'));
    }),
});
```

To install lodash, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161646/using-lodash-with-embercli/38594067#38594067)

To iterate it in hbs,

```
{{#each resultModel as |item|}}
        <div class='row'>
            {{#each item as |group|}}
                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                        {{#link-to 'groups.show' group.id}}{{group.name}}{{/link-to}}
                </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

This is one way of approach. there may be other simple approaches to this.

Comment: Thanks. Should also mention you have to add `toArray()` to `this.get('model')` or else you will get an invalid array length error.

Comment: `chunk` method expects `Array` but `findAll` promise will resolve to `RecordArray`. thanks for pointing it. updated my answer.